# Proguard issues with Apache Legacy (while not using the library)

Tags: android, apache, proguard, android-proguard

I'm unable to generate a signed APK with obfuscation. I'm getting the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]                                             
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                                    
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                             
:app:checkReleaseManifest                                                                   
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE                                                               
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2320Library UP-TO-DATE                   
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72320Library UP-TO-DATE                              
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2320Library UP-TO-DATE                                   
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72320Library UP-TO-DATE                           
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library UP-TO-DATE                                
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2320Library UP-TO-DATE                    
:app:prepareComBignerdranchAndroidRecyclerviewMultiselect02Library UP-TO-DATE               
:app:prepareComFlipboardBottomsheetCommons150Library UP-TO-DATE                             
:app:prepareComFlipboardBottomsheetCore150Library UP-TO-DATE                                
:app:prepareComJoshdholtzSentrySentryAndroid121Library UP-TO-DATE                           
:app:prepareComScottyabAescrypt001Library UP-TO-DATE                                        
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid101Library UP-TO-DATE                                       
:app:prepareOrgSolovyevAndroidViewsLinearLayoutManager05Library UP-TO-DATE                  
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies                                                             
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE                                                          
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE                                                  
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE                                                  
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE                                                       
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE                                                          
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE                                                    
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                                    
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                                       
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE                                                      
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE                                                     
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE                                                      
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE                                                 
:app:compileRetrolambdaRelease UP-TO-DATE                                                   
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE                                                           
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE                                                       
:app:lintVitalRelease                                                                       
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE                                                       
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE                                
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease                                     
ProGuard, version 5.2.1                                                                     
Reading input...                                                                            
Reading program jar commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/fd32786786e2adb664d5ecc965da47629dca14ba
Reading program jar me.tatarka/gradle-retrolambda/3.2.4/54ada546a04c36af9a2c7215c17f599e42bd
Reading program jar com.michaelpardo/activeandroid/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/4ab7b0182975bc57c49efc5e0b
Reading program jar javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/479c1e06db31c432330183f5cae684
Reading program jar com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.7.0/9e9eeaf9948ee4d6c3ab354e8dc14368f1
Reading program jar com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor/3.0.1/1d232df84491c0453e0770025
Reading program jar com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.0.1/b34c1f2d993044656e87f88970b6818e99e886
Reading program jar com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.0.0-beta4/bd49baf667542c7d06f71e
Reading program jar com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-gson/2.0.0-beta4/de5935a367ba5e343e9df7
Reading program jar com.squareup.okio/okio/1.6.0/98476622f10715998eacf9240d6b479f12c66143/ok
Reading program jar com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.0.0-beta4/739e00dea1f0ac04fdb9b6160d66
Reading program jar m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.2.0/support-anno
Reading program jar se.akerfeldt/okhttp-signpost/1.1.0/544600ae042f8fc113acb612ef30c69144b68
Reading program jar com.google.code.gson/gson/2.4/695b63d702f505b9b916e02272e3b6381bade7f/gs
Reading program jar com.jakewharton/butterknife/7.0.1/d5d13ea991eab0252e3710e5df3d6a9d4b21d4
Reading program jar oauth.signpost/signpost-core/1.2.1.2/bf95955dcf3d5a78c201e49b0c336787ea7
Reading program jar io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.0/748f0546d5c3c27f1aef07270ffea0c45f0c42a4/rxjav
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.2.0/
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/io.reactivex/rxandroid/1.0.1/jars/
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.scottyab/aescrypt/0.0.1/jars/c
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.joshdholtz.sentry/sentry-andro
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.solovyev.android.views/linear-
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.bignerdranch.android/recyclerv
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/2
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vecto
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-vector
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/recyclerview-v
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.flipboard/bottomsheet-commons/
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.flipboard/bottomsheet-core/1.5
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.
Reading program jar /app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/jars/2/1f/main.
Reading program directoryapp/build/intermediates/classes/release] (filtered)                
Reading library jar [/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar]                         
Reading library jar [/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar] 
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]                     
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]               
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]         
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetapho
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.Soundex]     
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.Metaphone]   
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.RefinedSounde
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetapho
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BinaryCodec]   
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64]        
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex]           
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.Encoder]              
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec]         
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.BCodec]           
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.QCodec]           
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCod
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.net.RFC1522Codec]     
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryEncoder]        
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.StringEncoderComparato
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException]     
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryDecoder]        
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.EncoderException]     
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.StringEncoder]        
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.StringDecoder]        
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder]              
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]  
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]     
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]  
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]             
Reading library jar [/lib/libGoogleAnalytics.jar]                                           
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't read [/lib/libGoogleAnaly
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED                              
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.  
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/lib/libGoogleAnalytics.jar] (No such file or directory) 
Information:BUILD FAILED                                                                    
Information:Total time: 8.506 secs                                                          
Information:1 error                                                                         
Information:1 warning                                                                       
Information:See complete output in console
```

The weirdest thing is that I'm not using the Apache library or GoogleAnalytics library. I'm posting my gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }

    // Exclude the version that the android plugin depends on.
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.sythg"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "false"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'se.akerfeldt:okhttp-signpost:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.joshdholtz.sentry:sentry-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.solovyev.android.views:linear-layout-manager:0.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0' // optional
}
```

And my proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/diegobarrerarodriguez/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

########--------Retrofit + RxJava--------#########
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.retrofit.RetrofitJackson**
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn retrofit.**

-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
   long producerNode;
   long consumerNode;
}


# ALSO REMEMBER KEEPING YOUR MODEL CLASSES
-keep class com.something.sthg.model.** { *; }

################### Retrolambda
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*

################### ButterKnife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

################### ActiveAndroid
-keep class com.activeandroid.** { *; }
-keep class com.activeandroid.**.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.Model
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.serializer.TypeSerializer

################### Signpost OAuth
-libraryjars /lib/libGoogleAnalytics.jar
-libraryjars /lib/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /lib/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

################### Annotation
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

################### Apache
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.compatibility.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, just use -dontnote for every error. Like thus:

```
-dontnote android.net.http.**
-dontnote org.apache.commons.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
```